# Access an intermediate layer in Keras after multi_gpu_model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

As stated in [this issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11929), Keras' `multi_gpu_model` alters the apparent layer structure of a model.

For instance, when the layers from an original model looks are:

```
>>> [l.name for l in my_model.layers]
[input, conv2d_1, conv2d_2, maxpool_1, conv2d_3, maxpool_2, dense_1, dense_2, dense_3]
```

After using `multi_gpu_model(my_model)`, then the layers will become:

```
>>> new_model = multi_gpu_model(my_model)
>>> [l.name for l in new_model.layers]
[input, lambda_1, lambda_2, lambda_3, lambda_4, model_1, dense_3]
```

I am trying to access the output from the layer `maxpool_2` from the original model, in order to use it into a different, subsequent model. How can I access the original `maxpool_2` layer's output after using `multi_gpu_model`?

Note 1: as `old_model` has not been trained, I have no interest in getting the output from `old_model.get_layer('maxpool_2')`. Only the outputs from the **trained** `new_model` are interesting here.

Note 2: trying to call `new_model.get_layer('maxpool_2')` will trigger ValueError: No such layer: maxpool_2.

Answer (score 0):

From [Keras source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/utils/multi_gpu_utils.py) it seems that the original model shares its weights with the multi-gpu model:

Therefore suffice to do the following the access the intermediate layer:

```py
old_model.get_layer('maxpool_2').output
```

Which will use the output of the **trained** model.